# Coding macro to auto-update chart data ranges , keep getting Runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm new to VBA and trying to code a macro in excel auto-update the data ranges for the charts on the current worsheet to correspond with the active sheet rather than the template I've created, and I'm getting a pretty finnicky run-time error 1004: 'application or object defined error" I had this macro working earlier with another template, but it has not any more since I changed the ranges to accommodate additional charts on the new template I am using. The line throwing the exception is:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
    "=" + datas + "!$F$2:$F$51"
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

```
        Sub app_template_data_update()
'
' app_template_data_update Macro
'

'

    ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("K3")
    datas = ActiveSheet.Range("K3")
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
        "=" + datas + "!$F$2:$F$51"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "=" + datas + "!$H$2:$H$51"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = _
        "=" + datas + "!$F$52:$F$101"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
        "=" + datas + "!$H$52:$H$101"

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
        "=" + datas + "!$F$62:$F$219"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "=" + datas + "!$H$62:$H$219"

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
        "=" + datas + "!$K$57:$K$66"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "=" + datas + "!$L$57:$L$66"

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "=" + datas + "!$O$75,$O$85"

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of `datas` when it fails? If the sheet name has spaces then add single-quotes around it.

Comment: it's a a string I use to name the sheet corresponding to my experiment file (e.g. 22MAR_C57B.sfwdat) which doesn't have any spaces, but I'll try the single quote thing anyways!

EDIT: didn't solve the issue, unfortunately. And the debugger is pointing back to the first " series collection"  line as the source of the error

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after OP's comments

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
        "=" + datas + "!$O$75,$O$85"
```

into

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    "=(" + datas + "!$O$75," + datas + "!$O$85)"
```

Comment: thanks for responding! the comma was actually there because I'm only taking information from two cells, not the whole range. Might I have to refer to the two cells entirely separately?

Comment: While VBA has enough overhead to substitute in the correct operator, the correct string concatenation operator is an ampersand (e.g. **&**), not a plus (e.g. **+**).

Comment: you're right. but I just went along with the Op's style to stress his code substantial modifications only. any how it's good to point that out.

Comment: @Jeeped switching + to & and that last line of code worked! Thank you so much

Comment: you mean that `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & datas & "!$O$75,$O$85"` worked? In my "system" it doesn't. While it does `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=(" + datas + "!$O$75," + datas + "!$O$85)"` or `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=(" & datas & "!$O$75," + datas + "!$O$85)"`